# Connection settings for development server for mongo on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, connection

If my production (heroku) connection settings in mongoid.yml are:

```
sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

What should my development connection settings look like? I'm running mongod in terminal having installed it with homebrew on osx.

So attempting a guess

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      host: localhost:27017
      database: locomotive_development
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

gives me 
"Problem:
  No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'."

Comment: What version of `mongoid` are you running?

Comment: hmm, running brew upgrade mongodb gives 2.4.3 already installed. So i guess 2.4.3.

Comment: to be clear, the production setup works, its development that wont connect.

Comment: There was an issue once on GitHub not sure if this will help - https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2894#issuecomment-14903927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the way of specifying hosts. It should be like this.

```
hosts:
  - localhost:27017
```

My mongoid.yml looks like this.

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: test_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

Comment: thanks perfect. I just couldn't find the documentation for the format it needed to be.